# Access methods and members of an Abstract class

Tags: c#, modbus-tcp

I am developing a Windows form to function as a modbus master Simulator.
I am using NModbus Library.
I am trying to display the response recieved from slave after read or write operation on the screen.
For example here is the read coil function code from NModbus library,

```
public class ModbusIpMaster : ModbusMaster
    {
        private ModbusIpMaster(ModbusTransport transport)
            : base(transport)
        {
        }


    /// Read from 1 to 2000 contiguous coils status.
    /// </summary>
   /// <param name="startAddress">Address to begin reading.</param>
   /// <param name="numberOfPoints">Number of coils to read.</param>
  /// <returns>Coils status</returns>
       public bool[] ReadCoils(ushort startAddress, ushort numberOfPoints)
       {
            return base.ReadCoils(Modbus.DefaultIpSlaveUnitId, startAddress, 
          numberOfPoints);
       }
}
```

The ReadCoils Method is found in base Class ModbusMaster which is an abstract class.

```
public abstract class ModbusMaster : ModbusDevice, IModbusMaster
    {
        internal ModbusMaster(ModbusTransport transport)
            : base(transport)
        {
        }
        public bool[] ReadCoils(byte slaveAddress, ushort startAddress, ushort 
                                      numberOfPoints)
        {
            ValidateNumberOfPoints("numberOfPoints", numberOfPoints, 2000);

            return ReadDiscretes(Modbus.ReadCoils, slaveAddress, startAddress, 
                                    numberOfPoints);
        }
        internal bool[] ReadDiscretes(byte functionCode, byte slaveAddress, 
                                ushort startAddress, ushort numberOfPoints)
        {
            ReadCoilsInputsRequest request = new 
                      ReadCoilsInputsRequest(functionCode, slaveAddress, 
                                              startAddress, numberOfPoints);
            ReadCoilsInputsResponse response = 
                    Transport.UnicastMessage<ReadCoilsInputsResponse>(request);

            return response.Data.Slice(0, request.NumberOfPoints).ToArray();
        }
}
```

i want to access the Read Discrete method to use the ReadCoilsInputResponse to display the response containing bytecount,slave id, data etc.
But when i create an instance of class ModbusIPMaster and use that instance to access the Read Discrete method, i am not able to access it.
Can anyone help me resolving this? or is there any other way to display the complete response received ?
Following is the link to refer to NModbus library
https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus

Answer (score 0):

ReadDiscretes is declared internal. Are you within the same assembly? If not then maybe you should consider declaring it public?

Comment: Yes i can see the problem now as you have pointed it,but i am using the  Nmodbus nuget package and i cant make any changes to the nuget package.

Comment: I think you should not use the methods that are declared internal. This is exactly why they are declared internal...

There are some ways to do it using reflection, but I wouldn't go there if I were you.